# Grep command, to remove lines containing a specified word

Tags: unix, grep

I want to use grep in the following way:

```
grep -v "END","EXPDTA" 1bmz_model1.pdb > 1bmz_model.pdb
```

I want the grep command to remove the lines which contain the words "END" and "EXPDTA", but all i get in the output, is a copy of the original file. The command works fine when I try to search and remove with a single word, but not with two words.

Comment: Is that really an AND or an OR?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
egrep -v "END|EXPDTA" infile > outfile
```

Comment: Of course, if one is using `egrep`, one can fulfil the questioner's desire of removing lines with _words_ that match, rather than everything that happens to have the three characters "END" within a larger word.  ☺

Comment: grep could do that too with `grep -v -e END -e EXPDTA ...`.

Comment: Could you provide some explanation about what your code does?

Comment: -v, --invert-match, Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

Comment: -e PATTERN, Use PATTERN as the pattern.  This can be used to specify multiple search patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with a hyphen (-).

Comment: man grep is your friend.

Comment: `egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using ggrep -E`