# Grep for many arguments

Tags: unix, grep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grep command, to remove lines containing a specified word](https://superuser.com/questions/351167/grep-command-to-remove-lines-containing-a-specified-word)

How do I grep for more than one words in one grep command. For example:

```
cat file.txt | grep -v 'word1' | grep -v 'word2'
```

to be transformed into something like:

```
cat file.txt | grep -v 'word1|word2'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `-E` for extended regular expressions, then you can use

```
grep -v -E '(word1|word2)'
```

or, shorter:

```
grep -vE '(word1|word2)'
```

Comment: If there's no search-text outside the brackets you can omit them: `grep -vE 'word1|word2'. You only need brackets when you search for something like `'orang(es| utangs)'`